# How does .reduce work with recursive functions in that situation?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how .reduce works with nested/recursive functions. In the example below, the console.logs show that the .reduce first compiles the functions and then runs them. What I can't understand is how that happens, does it just create a giant nested function, or does it do something else? 
From what I've seen and read, people say it creates a composed function which directly substitutes: e.g. `func3(acc(...args)`, where acc = `func2(func1(...args))`; but then won't the result be `func3(func2(func1(...args))(...args))`? The only solution I can think of is that the first `(...args)` disappears in the substitution of `acc`, so it becomes `func3(func2(func1(...args)))`.

```js
var numOfCallsToPipeFunction = 0;
var headerApplied = false;


// const pipe = (f, g) => (...args) => g(f(...args))
const pipe = function(f,g) {
  
  numOfCallsToPipeFunction++
  console.log('___________________________________________\n')
  console.log(" Call# " + numOfCallsToPipeFunction + " to pipe() function:");
  console.log('___________________________________________\n')
 
  console.log("  pipe() >>> 'f' input Parameter: "+f.name+"()\n")
  console.log("  pipe() >>> 'g' input Parameter: "+ g.name+"()\n")
 
    return function (...args) {
    if (!headerApplied) {
      console.log('=======================================================================\n')
       headerApplied = true
    }
    let retResult = g(f(...args))
 
    console.log("Results after running function(s): \n");
    console.log(f.name,g.name);
    console.log(" \n");
    console.log('Returned Result: ', retResult);
    console.log("\n");
    
    return retResult
  }
}
const startPipe  = function (...fns) {
   console.log('_______________________________________________________\n')
  console.log("StartPipe(): Input Parameters (i.e., ...fns)" )
  console.log('_______________________________________________________\n')
  console.log(fns.map(x=>x.name))
  return fns.reduce(pipe);
} 
startPipe(
  func1,
  func2,
  func3,
  func4,
)(1, 1)
 

function func1(num1, num2) {
   console.log('________________________________________________\n')
   console.log("Executing compose function with Data (...args): ")
   console.log('________________________________________________\n')
  console.log(`func1 called, applying:  ${num1} + ${num2}`)
  return num1 + num2
}
 
function func2(num1) {
  console.log(`func2 called, applying:  ${num1} * 2`)
  return num1*2
}
 
function func3(num1) {
   
   console.log(`func3 called, applying:  ${num1} - 2`)
   return num1-1
}

function func4(num1) {
  
 console.log(`func4 called, applying:  ${num1} + 2`)
 return num1+2
}
```

Comment: reduce starts first iteration with f=func1, g=func2 and at no point does it call any of the f,g functions.  It only returns the anonymous function return function(...args){} every time.  Nothing gets called until the very end when you explicitly call the composed function  returned by startPipe with (1,1)

Comment: spread operator ...args collects arguments (1,1) into array [1,1], which gets expanded back to g(f(1,1)) with the spread operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the reduce is finished, you get a composed function where each function, when executed, calls a reference to the last function in the iteration.  It does not execute the function(s), just returns the function as an object.
This is technically not recursion.  None of the functions are calling themselves.

The reduce functions basically like this snippet here:

```js
// an "unwrapped" version of the reduce iteration
f1 = func1
g1 = func2
acc1 = (x,y) =>
  g1(f1(x,y))

f2 = acc1
g2 = func3
acc2 = (x,y) =>
  g2(f2(x,y))

f3 = acc2
g3 = func4
acc3 = (x,y) =>
   g3(f3(x,y))

// acc3 has the resulting function
console.log("typeof acc3:", typeof acc3)
console.log("variable acc3 is a function object:", acc3)
// nothing has been called yet, you just have a function object that has chained calls to the other ones

console.log("calling acc3:")
console.log("result of calling acc3:", acc3(1,1))
console.log("\n\nI can call acc2:")
console.log("result of calling acc2:", acc2(1,1))

// how the spread operator functions:
function spread(...args) {
  console.log(args)
  console.log(...args)
}

spread(1,2,3,4)


function func1(num1, num2) {
   console.log('________________________________________________\n')
   console.log("Executing compose function with Data (...args): ")
   console.log('________________________________________________\n')
  console.log(`func1 called, applying:  ${num1} + ${num2}`)
  return num1 + num2
}
 
function func2(num1) {
  console.log(`func2 called, applying:  ${num1} * 2`)
  return num1*2
}
 
function func3(num1) {
   
   console.log(`func3 called, applying:  ${num1} - 2`)
   return num1-1
}

function func4(num1) {
  
 console.log(`func4 called, applying:  ${num1} + 2`)
 return num1+2
}
```

Comment: But can you clarify how that exactly works? Is the returned composed function ```(...args) => func4(func3(func2(func1(...args))))```? Or does something else happen?

Comment: returned function _acts_ like that, but is not actually the same as that.  Each layer func4 ( func3  has a layer of an anonymous function in between.  That is what my unwrapped code is supposed to try to show you.  notice how f2 = acc1, in other words the composed function in the last iteration

Comment: for rules and purposes, you can say that it simplifies to that. yes.  it does not turn into `func4(func3(func2(func1(...args))))(...args)` because func4 does not return a function.  more accurate would be to say it as `startPipe = (...args) => func4(func3(func2(func1(...args))))` and then `startPipe(1,1)`

Comment: Okay, so are they all in one big composed function, or is there a small composed function for each iteration that contains a reference to the composed function created in the previous iteration?

Comment: small composed function for each iteration that references the last.  functionally it has no real difference from one big composed function and can be seen as such, but as you might be able to imagine one big composed function would be more complicated to build when the input functions are dynamic

Comment: substitution? can you clarify what substitution you are referring to?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the nature of the code.  Nothing is being substituted or replaced.  You are just creating functions (see the functions as objects) with references to previous function in f, current function in g, that call g(f(params)) when they are called.  This creates a nesting of functions that is functionally the same as composing the functions.

Comment: Aha, could you also clarify one more thing, In your example and in general, when you substitute the returned function, how does it happen? As in, when the composed function starts executing does return the result of func1 to func2, or does it return the whole function? (In your example does acc1 execute and then is substituted as f2 in acc2?)

Comment: Ohh, I just read your reply, I mean what's the order of operation when the functions start executing

Comment: Just curious, are you coming from Haskell, or MatLab?

Comment: I know more of Haskell than MatLab, why?

Comment: The concepts you are talking about sound like native ideas from those languages, where functions can be treated as deterministic values.  You'll have less of that here in JS esp. web programming, although you can replicate a lot of the functionality and there is a general movement to go in that direction due to them being more rigorous.  Honestly IMHO they're more advanced concepts in the JS world.

Comment: So what is happening, is func1(1,1) executes and returns 2.  func2(2) returns 4.  func3(4) returns 2.  etc etc..  There is an intermediate function in between each

Comment: The reason func1 gets called first, is because the chain of functions passes (1,1) all the way through all the "acc" intermediate functions, until it reaches the bottom func1(...args), and then after that value evaluates and returns is passed to g, which is func2( <-anonymous_function(<-func1(...args)) )

Comment: yeah sorry, if I'm taking a lot of your time, I just really want to understand what's happening "under the hood". When I first came across this I was really confused. 
When I first looked at it in my head it went as you described, but I couldn't understand what happened to the arguments. I expected it to work like this: ``` (x,y) => g2 ( f2 ( x,y ))``` and f2 = acc1, when executed returns 2 and you end up with ``` (x,y) => g2 ( 2 ( x,y ))``` . Which seemed confusing and wrong.

Comment: I think you'll have to unsee the Haskell stuff a little bit here (which is a little unfortunate because it's a cool way of seeing programming).  f2 = acc1 doesn't assign f2 to the value of acc1.  in other words acc1 does not equal 2.  it is a function object that can be called.  acc1(1,1) gives you 2.  but acc1 is reference to a function object that can be called.  so if you did fun = acc1, you could call fun(1,1) and get 2.

Comment: Ohh, I think I finally start to get it, so f2(x,y) in your example works as a reference to acc1() and calls acc1(x,y). x and y being passed through f2 as a reference to acc1.

Comment: `(x,y)=>g2(f2(x,y))` is (almost) the same as `function(x,y){ return g2(f2(x,y)) }`.  which is a function object.  f2 points to the same function object as acc1, which is `(x,y) =>
  g1(f1(x,y))`, which is actually an object.  I could write acc1 = 2 next, and acc1 would no longer be a function, but the number 2

Comment: x and y are stored in closures and when the functions start executing and it reaches, for example, f2 it directly passes the values passed as (...args) to the function stored in memory, and all this happens by reference to the function. Is that somewhat right?

Comment: ya, you've got it.